# How can I get the all attributes together in one page for the each of categories

Tags: magento

How can I get the all attributes together in one page for the each of categories

I want to show the filter in this way!

Season
 spring
 summer
 fall
 winter

Color
 red
 green
 blue
 black
 yellow

price
 0 to 50
 50 to 100

for each categories

please guide me.
I tried to get the layer navigation,but it din't

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you are talking about layered navigation on category page. 
There are two things you can do

- insure the category's option value **Is Anchor** is **Yes** on Display Settings tab
  `Category Name -> Display Settings -> Is Anchor`
- and custom attributes are set **Yes** for **Use In Layered Navigation** option on **Frontend Properties** section.
  `custom attribute name -> Frontend Properties -> Use In Layered Navigation`

for details you can check [this link](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/layered-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Thanx,but I need to get it by programmatic
I used the custom coding to get all attributes in layers navigation

```
$layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
$category_id = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $category_id->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($currentCategoryId);
$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
$attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
{
    echo $attribute->getAttributeCode().'<br />';

  if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
     $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_price';
  } elseif ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal') {
     $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_decimal';
  } else {
     $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_attribute';
  }
  Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)
  ->setLayer($layer)->setAtributeModel($attribute)->init();
    foreach($result->getItems() as $option) 
 {          
        echo $option->getFrontendLabel();
        echo $option->getLabel().'<br/>';
        //echo $option->getValue().'<br/>';
    }
}
```